# An abelian category is equivalent to a subcategory of the category of abelian groups

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I recently heard the statement that any abelian category is equivalent to a subcategory of **Ab**, the category of abelian groups.

Is this statement true, and if so where can I find a proof?

Comment: Look for Freyd-Mitchell's Embedding Theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freyd-Mitchell's embedding theorem states that any *small* abelian category is equivalent to a *full* subcategory of the category of $R$-modules for some (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$.

If you remove the adjective "full", you can have any *small* abelian category be  equivalent to a subcategory of $\mathbf{Ab}$ - it can be interesting to see how to derive that from the above (be careful though, that $R-\mathbf{mod}$ is not iself a subcategory of $\mathbf{Ab}$). But the notion of "subcategory", when it's not full is... well it's a bit odd, to say the least.

hunter pointed out in their answer that this is not a "serious" obstruction as you can perform most arguments in a small subcategory. This is true to some extent but one has to be careful though, to see which arguments are "local", in the sense that they indeed only depend on a small abelian subcategory containing the objects of interest; and which aren't.

For instance, arguments concerning infinite (co)limits can turn out to fail : it's easy to prove that in $R-\mathbf{mod}$, filtered colimits are exact; but this fails badly in general abelian categories (think about $^{op}$), and this is because "this diagram is a colimit diagram" is not a "local" condition : it depends on the whole category.

So Freyd-Mitchell's embedding theorem can help in understanding "local" statements about abelian categories, but not all statements though, so smallness is not only a useless set-theoretic condition.

For a proof, you can see references [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Freyd-Mitchell+embedding+theorem) (see the section *References*)

EDIT : as pointed out in the comments below, if you're not afraid of Grotbendieck universes, then this is not a serious obstruction, though the problems I mentioned above are still there, because exact fully faithful functors need not preserve (co)limits, or injectives/projectives. This seems to actually be the real reason why these types of arguments fail.

Comment: Dear Maxime, I don't think smallness is the (sole) reason for an embedding not preserving infinite (co)limits. First of all, if we work with Grothendieck universes, then we can always choose a universe $U$ in which our abelian category is small and have an embedding of the entire category into the category of $U$-small modules. Second, even in this case an exact fully faithful functor doesn't have to preserve (co)limits unless it is an equivalence. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jxt921 : I think you are completely right - I had convinced myself a while ago that it was about smallness and never really thought about it again so I didn't update this idea. I'll correct my answer, thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 0):

This is Freyd's embedding theorem. It's false as stated for set-theoretic reasons; you need the additional hypothesis that the category is small. My understanding is that this is not a serious obstruction, even though most abelian categories you care about are not small, because you can always make whatever argument you wanted to make in a small subcategory; don't know the details though.

Comment: It's a serious obstruction in the sense that it can't usually be a *full* subcategory. If you allow module categories, however, this works for the most basic argument. Be careful, however, that some arguments aren't "local", in that they can't be performed in a small subcategory (e.g. arguments involving (co)limits or some involving projective/injective objects); and in that sense it can also be a serious obstruction