# Mitchell's embedding theorem in Rotman's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Theorem 5.99 in Rotman's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" is

> If $\mathcal{A}$ is a small abelian category, then there is a covariant full faithful exact functor $F: \mathcal{A} \to Ab$.

Is this correct? I thought one gets only a covariant full faithful exact functor $F: \mathcal{A} \to \text{R-Mod}$ for some (maybe non-commutative) ring $R$ not necessarily $R = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I agree with you, this feels like a significant typo. I'm not sure though since I never actually use Freyd-Mitchell (because I've yet to see a single instance of it being used carefully and I don't know what subtleties there are to be aware of)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3726610/681666) answer seems relevant.

Comment: Rotman cites Mitchel's book there, concrete page. But if you go to the book you will see that Mitchell talks about $R-Mod$. It's a mistake in Rotman's book, plus unlikely to be true.

Comment: @freakish But I think it should then be no problem simply to replace $Ab$ by $R-Mod$ at the significant places?

Comment: @psl2Z I don't know, I didn't read the book. I just looked up the fragment.

Comment: @FShrike Is there maybe a list of errata for this book? I found something, but the link is broken: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Erotman/errhomalg.pdf

Comment: @FShrike I’m confused by your reticence to use the theorem and by the claim that it’s never used carefully. It’s certainly possible to misuse it, basically by assuming that properties of $R$-Mod that aren’t determined by finite limits and colimits will be inherited by $\mathcal A$ (such as the higher ABn axioms about exactness of filtered colimits and the like.) But is the need not to draw conclusions that aren’t in the theorem really any different from any other serious theorem?

Comment: @KevinArlin I don’t claim it’s never used carefully, just that I’ve never seen it used carefully. The technique of how to properly use it (and actually check you can get a small subcategory to apply it to) has never been shown to me. And I’ve seen enough categorical mistakes in textbooks like Weibel’s to be wary. I’ve also never seen a situation where it was needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotman's errata for *An Introduction to Homological Algebra* can still be found on the Internet Archive [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230523102642/https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Erotman/errhomalg.pdf), and they do indeed include a correction to this theorem:

"Page 316 line 15 should read $F: \mathcal{A} \to _R\!\!\mathbf{\text{Mod}}$ for some ring $R$."

It's not true that every small abelian category has a full exact embedding into the category of abelian groups.

If it were, then every object of a small abelian category would have an endomorphism ring isomorphic to that of an abelian group.

And so every right Noetherian ring $R$ would be the endomorphism ring of an abelian group, since $R\cong\text{End}(R_R)$, where $R_R$ is the regular right module, which is an object of the small abelian category of finitely generated right $R$-modules.

But there is no abelian group with endomorphism ring $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, since such a group would have the structure of a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and no vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ has endomorphism ring $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

There may well be simpler arguments.

Comment: Thank you for this example and the link. So, basically I think I have to replace Ab by R-Mod at the significant places where the full embedding theorem is used?

Comment: @psl2Z Yes, that’s right. And the ring $R$ will depend on the particular small abelian category that you want to embed.